# Do APs talk to each if a client is nearer to the other one? (sticky-client-problem)

Tags: network, access-point

Question above.

I've read a little bit about it the sticky client problem and those are the solutions I've found:

- talking to the client that there is another (better) AP
- don't support lower rates that the client automatically gets disconnected from the "bad" AP
- Just kick the client off

How is the first ("friendly") solution working? Are the APs talking with each other!?

Comment: Roaming is completely up to the client.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do two autonomous APs talk to each other? No. They are completely independent entities. In this case, the client chooses which to use.

In a managed environment (lightweight access points with a wireless lan controller), the controller can signal a client to "roam", but short of refusing to allow connections to other APs, once again, the client is free to associate with whatever AP it wants.

Comment: But when the client chooses which to use, how is the sticky-client-problem solved then?